# How do i open a media source in sapui5?

Tags: sapui5

I have a sap gateway service which returns a filestream from type /iwbep/cl_mgw_abs_data=>ty_s_media_resource

my question is: how do i open this in sapui5?

so in sapui5 i have a list with listitems. those listitems have to open the filestream(pdf) when clicked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Krisho

OPTION 1.- open the URL in a separte tab. Something like this.

```
<Button text="Open PDF" press="onPress"></Button>

onPress: function(oEvent){
    sap.m.URLHelper.redirect("https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/maintenancestrategy.pdf", true)
}
```

Here a snippet: https://jsbin.com/xowocipuye/edit?html,output

OPTION 2 - Create a iFrame

Something like this:

```
  createContent : function(oController) {
            var html = new sap.ui.core.HTML();
            html.setContent("<div id=\"divPdf\"><iframe id='pdfFrame' style=\"height:1000px;\"></iframe>");
            return new sap.m.Page({
                  title : "PDF View",
                  showNavButton : true,
                  navButtonPress : oController.fnGoback,
                  content : [ html ],
                  footer : new sap.m.Bar({
                  })
            });
      }
```

I picked this last snippet from this old post:
https://blogs.sap.com/2014/02/20/sapui5-pdf-display/

Answer (score 0):

The OData URL giving you the PDF will be looking like this.
/sap/opu/odata/......./$value

You have two options.

1. Upon selecting the item, open the corresponding URL in a new Tab.
   New tab will automatically render the PDF
2. Create a UI5 view which
   contains an iframe (using UI5 html control) and render the above URL
   inside the iframe.